# Javascript Auto refresh after video is played

Tags: javascript, video, refresh

I am trying to implement a feature where my index will auto refresh after one of the auto played videos play. I have tried various scripts yet none seem to work.

```js
var videos = [
    'D1sZ_vwqwcE',
    'J7IMwop3RHs',
    'BC_Ya4cY8RQ',
    'HPc8QMycGno',
    'JDglMK9sgIQ',
    'gHssu4WOHug',
    'hgKDu5pp_fU',
    '5LILChvqUo4',
    '4HVjldqWx4w',
    '4UwH97qI0aM'
];

var index=Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
index.onended = function() {
            window.open("index.html", "_self");
      };

var html='<div class="video-background"><div class="video-foreground"><iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' +videos[index] + '?controls=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp" allow="autoplay""></iframe></div></div>';
document.write(html);
```

What isn't working is the refresh script. I'm not sure if I'm linking it to the right variable or something.

```js
var index=Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
index.onended = function() {
            window.open("index.html", "_self");
      };
```

*note* the first line runs fine. It's the next 3 that I don't understand.

(this won't autoplay on chrome unless you hit ctrl+r. Since Chrome changed its autoplay policy.)